# Получить пустую строку из консоли

Tags: golang

Наверное, так себе вопрос, но все же. Получаю ввод от пользователя:

```
fmt.Print("Введите номер сервера: ")
fmt.Scan(&serverNumber) 
fmt.Print("Введите ID сессии: ")
fmt.Scan(&SessionID)
fmt.Print("Нужно ли управление?")
fmt.Scan(&control)
```

Как получить ввод пустой строки? При нажатии <kbd>enter</kbd>, ввод не принимается только строка перескакивает.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`fmt.Scanln`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln):

```golang
fmt.Print("Нужно ли управление?")
fmt.Scanln(&control)
```

Из документации:

> Scan, Fscan, Sscan treat newlines in the input as spaces.
>
> Scanln, Fscanln and Sscanln stop scanning at a newline and require that the items be followed by a newline or EOF.